# Cloning SCNNode subclass

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a `SCNNode` subclass names `Model3D`. It adds a few properties, that should be passed to a new instance when cloning the node. This is more o less how this looks like:

```
public class Model3D: SCNNode {
...
    private var modelURL: URL!

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override final public func clone() -> Self {
        let clone = super.clone() as! Self
        clone.modelURL = modelURL
        return clone
    }
...
}
```

And this usually works, but sometimes it crashes on `let clone = super.clone() as! Self`. I have no idea why. This should always work, but maybe I'm missing something. Anyone have some ide why this might be happening, and why only very rarely? This is how I initialize this object in the first place:

```
public required init?(modelURL: URL) {
    super.init()
    guard let scnNode = Self.loadModel(fromURL: modelURL) else { return nil }
    self.modelURL = modelURL
    self.castsShadow = false // Shadows can be enabled by configuration
    addChildNode(scnNode)
}

class func loadModel(fromURL url: URL) -> SCNNode? {        
    guard let rootNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: url) else { return nil }
    rootNode.load() 
    return rootNode
}
```

Comment: Dated, but you might check instruments and see if it's leaking since it is an intermittent issue as I have seen some posts about that in the past.  I tried cloning with mixed results and moved away from it, but it might have been my problem and not Scenekit.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tested it in profiler, and didn’t find any leaks related to this.

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace of the crash?